# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. Вопрос связан с размером окна приложения и ошибкой при его изменении. Как решить?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

Данная ошибка возникает после изменения размера окна кнопкой "свернуть" или же изменения размеров окна до минимума посредством уменьшения самого окна программы после вызова дочерней формы.

Я использую вот такую функцию для перехвата значений в самой операционной системе Windows.

```
private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
     protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
     const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
     const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;
     const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
      if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
                {
     int wParam = (m.WParam.ToInt32 () & 0xFFF0);
                    if (wParam == SC_MINIMIZE)
     formSize = this.ClientSize;
                    if (wParam == SC_RESTORE)
      this.Size = formSize;
                }
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
```

Дополнительно использую функцию:

```
    public void AdjustForm()
            {
                switch (this.WindowState)
                {
                    case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                        this.Padding = new Padding(8, 8, 8, 0);
                        break;
                    case FormWindowState.Normal:
                        if (this.Padding.Top != borderSide)
                            this.Padding = new Padding(borderSide);
                   
                        break;
                } 
    }
```

Далее на самой кнопке указываю:

```
private void SVERNUT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }
```

Вот настройки дочерних форм:

```
    private void OpenWorkerPanel(Form childForm, object btnSender)
            {
                
                if (activeForm != null)
                {
                    activeForm.Close();
                }
                ActivateButton(btnSender);
                activeForm = childForm;
                childForm.TopLevel = false;
                childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                childForm.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                this.WorkerPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
                childForm.BringToFront();
                childForm.Show();
    
            }
```

Вот функция, вызывающая дочернюю форму:

```
private void PrinterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenWorkerPanel(new Forms.Form2Printer(), sender);
                
            }
```

Если я убираю вот эту строчку:

```
childForm.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

то кнопка "свернуть" и изменение размеров окна программы к ошибке не приводит.